# how to make a systemd service atomic; manual lock/pid file or does systemd feature exist?

Tags: linux, systemd

I have `mybackups.service` and `mybackups.timer`. I'd like `mybackups.service` to only ever have one running instance. That is, I want the following to happen:

### Case 1: timer already kicked off `mybackups.service`

If I run backups manually for some reason, `$ systemctl start mybackups.service` I want systemctl to say "skipping, already running"

### Case 2: I've manually kicked off `mybackups.service`

When `mybackups.timer` tries to start its service, on schedule, I'd like it to get stopped by systemd with, with some logged error, eg: `mybackups.service was already in progress`

### Case 3: Long-running service

Obviously I'd hopefully fix such clobbering, but if for some reason a `mybackups.service` was running really long, I'd hope the next kick-off by `mybackups.timer` would get the same treatement as case #2 *(ie: I'd hope it wouldn't start *another* service run)*

**tl;dr** I *could* *(and [I have](https://github.com/jzacsh/bin/blob/b73710888c23d/share/resticw.sh#L41-L49))* change the underlying program that `mybackups.service` starts to just **exit** when it finds an old PID file and a still-alive PID somewhere. However this such a general problem that I'm expecting[2] & **hoping systemd has options** for this.

[2]: eg: systemd already tracks the whole PID tree of its services, it seems like the perfect candidate to do this correctly for you.

Comment: To reliably implement mutexes within scripts without the risk of stale pidfiles, use BSD file locks via `flock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html

> Note that in case the unit to activate is already active at the time the timer elapses it is not restarted, but simply left running. There is no concept of spawning new service instances in this case.

Answer (score 4):

That's already the default behavior. There is always at most one instance of the same unit, and systemd quietly refuses to queue a start job for a unit that's already starting or active.

---

(In fact, to achieve the *opposite* you would need template units, e.g. `foo@.service` can be started several times with different parameters. However, each such unit still remains unique; e.g. systemd won't start two copies of `foo@bar.service` either.)

Comment: Oh, great news, thanks! I just tried googling some more based on what you said, but still can't find any documentation about this. Do you mind linking to where/how you know this?

Comment: …seven years of systemd experience, I suppose?

Comment: k, well if you come across documentation/anything about this, and think of it, I'd appreciate an update/link :)